# How do I get the user details from the Single Sign-On (SSO) server with Pivotal Spring Cloud Gateway?

Tags: angularjs, single-sign-on, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-gateway

I have been able to configure Single Sign-On for my AngularJS app successfully using below documentation:

https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-gateway/1-0/getting-started.html#access-app-endpoint-at-gateway-path

When hitting the URL the app is redirected to our internal SSO page and the rest of the thing follows and works well.

At this point I am not sure how to get the details of the user that is logging in to the app. For example, user id of the person logging in?

Comment: I don't have a lab to test this at the moment, but have you looked at the Authorization header? It is possible to configure Spring Cloud Gateway to relay tokens, that would come through to your app in the Authorization header (since it's a bearer token). Again, I don't know off hand how the Pivotal SCG tile configures this, but it is possible with SCG, see https://spring.io/blog/2019/08/16/securing-services-with-spring-cloud-gateway.

Comment: @DanielMikusa I don't have the control over SCG. How do I check whether it is coming through to the app in the Authorization header?

Comment: Look at and/or print the headers in your app that is behind SCG, in particular the Authorization header. Not sure how to tell you how to do this as I don't know your app/setup. You could always put a test app behind SCG and look at the headers. Just use whatever language/frameworks that are familiar to you.

Comment: @DanielMikusa Hi Daniel. I am back at this problem again. So, my app is an Angular app with a Node.js backend. On the client side, I tried printing all the headers but can only see the headers for the requests made from the client side. Any hint on how I can pull the authorization details the first time app loads? I tried looking up in the documentation but I only see examples for Spring/Java

Comment: I think this is what you want -> https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-gateway/1-0/using-sso.html#tokenrelay. That will pass the id token of the logged in user and you should be able to get whatever info is included in the token. This is the docs for the TokenRelay should you want to look into it more. https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-security/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#_client_token_relay_in_spring_cloud_gateway.

Comment: Do keep in mind that you're running a client side application. The TokenRely filter is going to add that information to the request as it passes through to the gateway.  Browser -> SCG -> (added here) -> your server app. Your server app will respond as normal, likely with your static HTML/CSS. If you want the client side app to have access to that info, your server side app needs to pass it along.

Comment: @DanielMikusa Perfect! I could successfully read the authorization header by rendering it on the server side using Angular universal. Please post the details as an answer as it might help someone else looking for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the user details in a service that sits behind a Spring Cloud Gateway instance, you need to use the TokenRelay filter.

https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-gateway/1-0/using-sso.html#tokenrelay

This can be enabled simply by adding `"token-relay": true` to your config:

Example:

```
$ cf bind-service cook my-gateway -c '{ "routes": [ { "path": "/cook/**", "sso-enabled": true, "token-relay": true } ] }'
```

The TokenRelay filter is documented here.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-security/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#_client_token_relay_in_spring_cloud_gateway

You also need to keep in mind that the TokenRelay filter is *only* going to pass the token along to the server application that is behind the gateway.

Ex: `Browser -> SCG -> (token id added here) -> your server app`

Your server app will respond as normal, likely with your static HTML/CSS. If you would like to access the user information from the client (i.e. browser/single page app/Angular app) then your server application will need to expose that information to your application.